# Can I run 32/64 bit mathematica on Ubuntu touch?

Tags: software-installation, ubuntu-touch, compatibility

I'm going to install Ubuntu on my  google nexus 9 tablet based on  64-bit Nvidia tegra dual denver processor.

After that can I run Wolfram Mathematica 32/64 bit,or any other 3rd party desktop applications for linux ,on it?

Comment: Did  you try [Mathics](http://www.mathics.org)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That depends on the available instruction set(s) of the processor architecture of the tablet computer. According to [Mathematica's official system requirements](//www.wolfram.com/mathematica/system-requirements.html), Intel x86 or AMD64 instruction set support is required. That means, you can't run Mathematica on an ARM processor driven (tablet) computer.

Comment: Thats might not be true. You can take Mathematica version from raspberry Pi, The package is at: http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/pool/main/w/wolfram-engine/    and try to install. I plan to try this. At least mathematica kernel when I tried to run from SD card asked for password. So in principle it is worth to try.

Comment: You're right. While the official release overview doesn't list it, there's an [announcement to the RPi comminity](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/157340).

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that the Mathematica kernel taken from RPI runs on an Aquaris 4.5 phone running Ubuntu Touch.

Short instruction how I proceeded:

1. On the phone, run the `sshd` demon, i.e in terminal I run `/usr/sbin/sshd -D &"` (this allows password authentication, as was discussed in this forum)
2. Copy Mathematica from RPI to phone. I used `tar cvf - ./Wolfram | ssh -l phablet phoneIP 'tar xvf -'` when RPI and the phone were both connected to the same local network.
3. Login to the phone using `ssh` and edit the scripts in the `Executables` folder, replacing `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/sh -e`    (this may be optional)
4. Run the `Executables/math` script (Ensure it is executable! Do a `chmod +x ./math`, if not)
5. Pass the authentication procedure as for ordinary Mathematica. When finished, the math kernel starts and is working.

**Note.** Due to a terminal application bug (as of 2015-06-27) you cannot run the math script in the terminal. If you want to run it in phone's terminal application you can use temporal workaround: `ssh localhost` and then run math. Or even in one step `ssh localhost 'math'`, where math is assumed to be on your  path.